# How to use two dimensional array

Tags: c#

So I have following example:

I have those 3 strings:

```
string seq3 = "Zeile1: 5,4,2; Zeile2: 9,4,8; Zeile3: 5,3,6"; 
string seq4 = "Zeile1: 2,5,4,2; Zeile2: 4,1,7,8; Zeile3: 5,3,6,1; Zeile4: 9,2,3,5"; 
string seq5 = "Zeile1: 2,7,5,4,2; Zeile2: 9,4,1,7,8; Zeile3: 5,3,6,7,1; Zeile4: 9,2,3,5,0; Zeile5: 7,2,5,1,6";
```

So I need to split the string to become 5 4 2, etc. or 2 5 4 2
And I should output it like matrix.
E.g.:

```
5 4 2
9 4 8
5 3 6
```

At the end I need calculate the arithmetic mid value. `a + b / 2`

So here is my method for spliting, but the dimensions don't work. I Think the method signature is wrong, I should use two dim array.

```
private static string[,] myArray = new string[5, 5]; 

        public string Berechnen(string s)
        {
            string result ="";

            string[] ZeilenInhalt = s.Split(';');
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                string[] daten = ZeilenInhalt[i].Split(':');
                string[] ascciizahlen = daten[1].Split(',');
                for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                {
                    result = myArray[i, j] = ascciizahlen[j];
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Here is the method for the output

```
   public void Show()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < myArray.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < myArray.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    Console.Write($"{myArray[i, j]}");
                    int middle = Convert.ToInt32(myArray[i, j]);
                    Console.WriteLine($"{middle,1}");
                }

            }
        }
```

I used interpolate string so I can round it to comma.

The output should be smth like this:

```
5 4 2
9 4 8
5 3 6

Middle value: 123,2
```

I have only black screen.

Thanks,

Comment: Personally I prefer using Jagged arrays over multidiemnsional ones. But that is just personal preference. As for the output, where do you call show?

Comment: Have you checked the watch window ? Maybe it's just the output, that has trouble.
Is there any exception raised ? `result = myArray[i, j] = ascciizahlen[j];`this will overwrite your result, in each loop, the method will return only the last value array[4,4]

Comment: I call Berechnen and Show in Main, also the strings are in main

Comment: I'd expect an index out of range exception. Put a breakpoint and step it through in debugger. I bet you'll see it.

Comment: How do you come up with `123,2`?

Comment: @Fildor Yes I got now the index out of range exp.

Comment: @RufusL Only example, it comes smth different that was example how output should look like, I wanted to say that mid value should come after the matrix output

Comment: Yes, that's because you hardcode the array size to 5, but your split only gets you 3 or 4. You need to take that into account.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by mid value when you have a matrix of values. How do you calculate it from the matrix? How do you get the value `123,2` from `{{5,4,2},{9,4,8},{5,3,6}}`

Comment: @RufusL I need to calculate the arithmetic value ```a+b / 2``` this is the formel, I though like this ```int middle = Convert.ToInt32(myArray[i, j])/2```; I'm not sure if this is the right way to calculate it.

Comment: @RufusL I don't think that matters for the question. But it looks like a median over all elements. It also seems `123.2` was only some arbitrary value and not the actual result from that matrix.

Comment: When someone says "the output should be _____" I would expect that the sample output is at least accurate based on the sample input. I really have no idea where to start with this one, it seems so broad and there is no specific question. And I can't write a working example since there is no correlation between the input and output that can be used to test it. For now I'm going to vote to close as "unclear what you're asking".

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, perhaps you could do something like this?

```
        string seq3 = "Zeile1: 5,4,2; Zeile2: 9,4,8; Zeile3: 5,3,6";
        string seq4 = "Zeile1: 2,5,4,2; Zeile2: 4,1,7,8; Zeile3: 5,3,6,1; Zeile4: 9,2,3,5";
        string seq5 = "Zeile1: 2,7,5,4,2; Zeile2: 9,4,1,7,8; Zeile3: 5,3,6,7,1; Zeile4: 9,2,3,5,0; Zeile5: 7,2,5,1,6";

        var resultArray = seq5.Split(';').Select(s => s.Split(':')[1].Trim().Split(',').Select(n => int.Parse(n)).ToArray()).ToArray();

        foreach (var subArray in resultArray)
        {
            foreach (var number in subArray)
            {
                Console.Write(number);
            }

            Console.WriteLine($" (line average: {subArray.Average()})");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Is the mid value of each subArray lines that you need ?

Comment: Then if you need the array average, you can do that : Console.WriteLine($"\nTotal average: {resultArray.Select(l => l.Average()).Average()}");

Comment: Please be sure you have using System.Linq; and please note Average() is a method. If it fails again please show us the code ?

Comment: I'm supposed to create the method

Comment: This is the error ```Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1929 'string[]' does not contain a definition for 'Average' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Average(IQueryable<int>)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable<int>'
```

Comment: Ok the problem is the type you are passing to the .Average() extension method. It can't be string[] (but it should be int[] or double[]). Be carefull when parsing :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this method for splitting:

```
public string[] GetMatrixFromString(string seq)
{           
     seq = seq.Replace("Zeile", "");
     var array = seq.Split(';');

     if(array.Length > 0)
     {
          string[] matrix = new string[array.Length];

          for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
          {
               var item = array[i];
               var matrixLine = item.Split(':')[1].Replace(",", " ");
               matrix[i] = matrixLine;
          }

          return matrix;
      }
      else
      {
          return null;
      }          
}
```

Be careful to check if return value is null, so that in this case it was not able to parse the string and create matrix.

For example:

```
string seq3 = "Zeile1: 2,5,4,2; Zeile2: 4,1,7,8; Zeile3: 5,3,6,1; Zeile4: 9,2,3,5";
var matrix = GetMatrixFromString(seq3);

if(matrix == null)
{
      Console.WriteLine("Unable to parse input");
}
else
{
      foreach (var line in matrix)
      {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
      }
}
```